# jquery and css in rails app: shifting a div to the left in response to a mouseover event not working

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, css

Hi I have a div containing a map. When the user mouseovers it I would like it to change its width from 80% to 50%, creating room on the righ, so as to accomodate an image which will appear on the right side.

I looked at some examples online of jquery event handling and tried to incorporate what I saw there into my own app. However, I think  I didn't quite get it right, since there is no response to the mouseover. Could someone please give me a hand with diagnosing the error since Im new to web development, rails and jquery.

Below are the relevant files from my rails project:

list.html.erb - contains all the HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />  
<script type="text/javascript"  
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Q&sensor=false"></script>  
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>  
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>  
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'listings' %>  
<body onload="initialize()">  
    <div id="control_panel">  
    <input type="button" onclick="getlistings();" value="Add Markers">  
    <input type="button" onclick="clearMarkers();" value="Remove Markers">  
    </div>  
    <div id="info"></div>  
    <div id="map_canvas" onmouseover="moveLeft();" ></div>  
</body>
```

map.js.erb - contains the javascript and jquery functions

```
function moveLeft()  
{  
    $(function(){ $("#map_canvas").bind("mouseover", shiftLeft) });  
    $(function(){ $("#map_canvas").bind("mouseleave", shiftLeft) });  
}  

function shiftLeft(evt)  
{  
    $("#map_canvas").toggleClass("shifted_mapCanvas");  

}
```

css file:

```
#map_canvas  
{  
  width: 90%;  
  height: 90%;  
  margin-left: auto;  
  margin-right: auto;  
  html   
  {   
    height: 100%   
   }  
  body   
  {   
    height: 100%;   
    margin: 10;   
    padding: 10   
   }  

}

.shifted_mapCanvas  
{  
  width: 50%;  
  height: 90%;  
  margin-left: auto;  
  margin-right: auto;  
  html    
  {   
    height: 100%   
   }  
  body   
  {   
    height: 100%;   
    margin: 10;   
    padding: 10   
   }  
}
```

Comment: banditKing, you need to be more careful in how you format your questions. This is the third time I've noted one of your questions without code formatting. To format code simply enclose it in backticks (```) or indent it all at least 4 spaces.

Comment: @ Andrew, apologize, could you please point me to the section where I can refer to for code format of html? I will go over that today. Thanks

Comment: I tried to find it in the meta section but wasn't successful, I wanted to get a screen print so I can paste it on my computer. Is there a page where all the formating info is together? or all I need is the backticks ?thanks

Comment: Formatting instructions are on the sidebar on the left when you write a question. To format something as code just select the whole code block after you pasted it in and hit the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try and answer only the question you've asked, you're calling jQuery functions (`$("#map_canvas").bind("mouseover", shiftLeft)`), but where did you load jQuery?

Also, you're trying to trigger javascript calls inline, which is definitely not the recommended approach. Instead, assuming jQuery is loaded, if you used:

```
<script>
$('div#map_canvas').hover({
  function() { $(this).toggleClass('shifted_mapCanvas'); },
});
</script>
```

... it should work. See the docs for [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

---

To cover some other issues:

banditKing, respectfully, you need to go back to the beginning and start over. You've posted several questions over the past few days that illustrate you don't understand (1) HTML, (2) CSS, and (3) Rails at a basic level.

Here is how I can tell:

1) You should almost certainly not have a rails view called `list.html.erb`, it should probably be `views/lists/show.html.erb` or `views/lists/index.html.erb`. See [Creating A Resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-resource) in the Rails Guide.

2) A Rails view should not include the body tag, and should probably not include meta or script tags. The body tag belongs in your layout, otherwise you're going to have to repeat that tag in every view to make sure each view has a body, or else you will have invalid markup on your page.

3) Your stylesheet is SCSS, not CSS, which is fine except that you're trying to do things that totally don't make sense in the DOM. You're nesting styles for the HTML and BODY tags, which *must* be outside of the divs you're nesting them in... in other words, the SCSS you're creating is putting out impossible CSS definitions for HTML elements that are totally invalid.

For 2 and 3, see [How to Make a Simple Valid HTML Document](http://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/itl/projects/projectChallenge/2005/webclass/).

I could go on about [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) as well, but by now I think you get the idea.

You need to back up and start by learning what HTML is, and how it works. I recommend starting at W3C Schools for [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp), [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp), and [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Then, go through Michael Hartl's [Rails 3 Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). You can do it free online or buy a book copy.

The first three tutorials should only take a few hours each, and the the Rails tutorial can probably be completed in a day or two. If you work through each of those, in order, you will save yourself **weeks** or even **months** of struggle with the kind of questions you're asking right now.

I **strongly** encourage you to work through those basics first, then come back to the project you're working on now.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't realize it. Thanks Andrew for your suggestions. I went on a friend's suggestions, that the best way to learn to program is to do it and not read book. So I was trying the get down and dirty approach. I will do the tutorials as you recommend and I have that book btw.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The *only* way to *master* programming is to do it, yes. And to have a project you are trying to accomplish is the best way to learn, rather than just learning for the sake of learning. But if you don't know the basics it's like trying to learn how to dive before learning how to swim. You need to start by learning (and doing) basic HTML and CSS, then you can learn how to do Rails. Learning a little JS would be good too, but you can learn that as you learn Rails. The good news is HTML and CSS are easy, so it won't take long to get back to where you're at now.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a bunch. I think, I understand now why a lot of the programming tasks seemd puzzling to me.